# Visual Studio 2015 startup projects list without extension

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, project, startup

In Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition there's an option to have a dropdown list for startup projects.
[Startup project option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjgXI.png)
In a sample project coming from Microsoft the list is available and I can choose from two startup projects - I don't need any extensions on this. [Dropdown list with startup projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhObG.png)
In case of my own project the option is ticked but there's no list like in the sample project.
Do somebody know how to get that list? I've searched for options in the solution and project properties without luck.
The mentioned sample project can be found on the following link: [Geolocation sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66)